# Why the logic for array conversion and HTML parsing is not working in following scenario?

Tags: php, arrays, xpath, html-parsing, domdocument

I've an associative array titled `$allFeeds` (after executing `print_r($allFeeds);`) as follows :

**Note :** The actual associative array `$allFeeds` is very large. For the understanding purpose I've only put one element from this large array.

```
   Array
   (
      [0] => Array
      (
         [feed_image] => Array
         (
           [0] => <a href="http://52.1.47.143/photo/928/2_onclick_ok/userid_244/"  class=" js_photo_item_928  photo_holder_image" rel="928" ><img src="http://52.1.47.143/file/pic/photo/2015/04/9bd387c6442135834298d6a17b3f9555_240.jpg"  alt=""  width="180"  height="160"  class="photo_holder" /></a><br />
           [1] => <a href="http://52.1.47.143/photo/927/8/userid_244/" class=" js_photo_item_928  photo_holder_image" rel="927"><img src="http://52.1.47.143/file/pic/photo/2015/04/6eb60ee0e258223ef72a9a632d0ce429_240.png"  alt="" height="84" width="150"  class="photo_holder"  userid="244" /></a>
         )
      )
    )
```

First of all I want to check whether the key `['feed_image']` is present in an inner array of associative array $allFeeds. If it's present convert the array `$allFeeds[$key]['feed_image']` by changing the image path of each array element as follows :

**Note :** I want to create the new array from 'src' attribute's value of each  tag. You can observe in this case too.

```
   Array
   (
      [0] => Array
      (
         [feed_image] => Array
         (
           [0] => 2015/04/9bd387c6442135834298d6a17b3f9555%s.jpg
           [1] => 2015/04/2015/04/6eb60ee0e258223ef72a9a632d0ce429%s.png
         )
      )
    )
```

I tried following code but it didn't work out for me. I don't understand what mistake I'm making. It would be great if somebody help me in correcting my mistake and get the desired output.

```
$cnt = 0;
foreach($allFeeds as $key => $value) {
  if(isset($allFeeds[$cnt]['feed_image']) && is_array($allFeeds[$cnt]['feed_image'])) {
    $allFeeds[$cnt]['feed_image'][$key] = array_map(function($item) {
      $dom = new DOMDocument;
      $dom->loadHtml($item);
      $src = simplexml_import_dom($dom)->xpath('//img/@src');
      if(!isset($src[0])) {
        return false;
      }
      $components = explode('photo/', $src[0]);            
        return end($components);          
    }, $feed['feed_image']);
    $allFeeds[$cnt]['feed_image'][$key] = array_filter($allFeeds[$cnt]['feed_image'][$key]);
  }
  $cnt++;
}
```

Can someone please help me by providing reliable and efficient solution to the issue I'm facing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some small bugs in your code, see adjustments below:

```
$allFeeds = Array
(
    0 => Array
    (
        'feed_image' => Array
        (
            0 => '<a href="http://52.1.47.143/photo/928/2_onclick_ok/userid_244/"  class=" js_photo_item_928  photo_holder_image" rel="928" ><img src="http://52.1.47.143/file/pic/photo/2015/04/9bd387c6442135834298d6a17b3f9555_240.jpg"  alt=""  width="180"  height="160"  class="photo_holder" /></a><br />',
            1 => '<a href="http://52.1.47.143/photo/927/8/userid_244/" class=" js_photo_item_928  photo_holder_image" rel="927"><img src="http://52.1.47.143/file/pic/photo/2015/04/6eb60ee0e258223ef72a9a632d0ce429_240.png"  alt="" height="84" width="150"  class="photo_holder"  userid="244" /></a>',
            2 => 'No image, should be removed',
        )
    )
);

$cnt = 0;
foreach($allFeeds as $key => $value) {
  if(isset($allFeeds[$cnt]['feed_image']) && is_array($allFeeds[$cnt]['feed_image'])) {
    // $allFeeds[$cnt]['feed_image'][$key] = array_map(function($item) {
    $allFeeds[$cnt]['feed_image'] = array_map(function($item) {
      $dom = new DOMDocument;
      $dom->loadHtml($item);
      $src = simplexml_import_dom($dom)->xpath('//img/@src');
      if(!isset($src[0])) {
        return false;
      }
      $components = explode('photo/', $src[0]);
        return end($components);
      // }, $feed['feed_image']);
      }, $allFeeds[$cnt]['feed_image']);

      // $allFeeds[$cnt]['feed_image'][$key] = array_filter($allFeeds[$cnt]['feed_image'][$key]);
      $allFeeds[$cnt]['feed_image'] = array_filter($allFeeds[$cnt]['feed_image']);
  }
  $cnt++;
}

print_r($allFeeds);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [feed_image] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015/04/9bd387c6442135834298d6a17b3f9555_240.jpg
                    [1] => 2015/04/6eb60ee0e258223ef72a9a632d0ce429_240.png
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Side note: If you do not have a specific reason not to do so, you could remove the `$cnt` variable and replace all occurrences of it with `$key`.